# Importing an STM32CubeMX project with a newer version into an older version of STM32CubeIDE

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide, stm32cubemx

I am using STM32CubeIDE (on Win10 OS), which is based on STM32CubeMX version '6.2.0'. I have a project configuration file (**my_project.ioc**) created with STM32CubeMX version '6.4.0'. When I try to import the project using the "STM32 Project from an Existing STM32CubeMX Configuration File (.ioc)" option in STM32CubeIDE, I receive the following error:

"Invalid Input: '**my_project.ioc**' file content is not supported.
This file has been generated with STM32CubeMX version '**6.4.0**'. Your current STM32CubeMX version is '**6.2.0**'.
Please check for an update: Help > Check for Updates"

I am unable to update my STM32CubeIDE version due to other projects in late development stages. Is there any solution or workaround to import the project into my current version of STM32CubeIDE without updating the IDE? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know what OS you are using, but certainly on Linux you can have multiple versions of CubeIDE installed. I've got 4 versions installed on this Ubuntu machine.

Comment: It's very unlikely that there will be any way to do this automatically.  However, the file is text based so you can just start setting up the options manually in the old IDE and compare the files until the contents look the same, minus any features that are only available in the new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do it.

Open the ioc file with your favorite text editor and replace the two following values with the one you want to use :

- MxCube.Version=`set here the version you want`
- MxDb.Version=`the DB version might be the same for 6.4.0 and 6.2.0 I guess, if not, use an older database version`

Then, open your old version of MX and load the ioc.

**However** and for logical reason of having the latest version, updates and bug fixes, you should consider installing alongside your existing version the previous one.
You can indeed have several versions of MX as well as CubeIDE as long as you change the default installation path so it doesn't override your default version set in the environment variable of your computer.

[image: custom MX]

Comment: This **soled the issue** of importing New configuration file into an old STM32CubeIDE.
It was scary thing to do, since the first line of the ioc file is:
_#MicroXplorer Configuration settings - do not modify_
yet I followed @Issylin orders:
old:
MxCube.Version=6.2.0
MxDb.Version=DB.6.0.20
new:
MxCube.Version=6.4.0
MxDb.Version=DB.6.0.40
it is working.